# Should we cover weep holes with wire mesh?

Tags: walls, brick, pest-control, weep-hole

We just bought our first home and we had advice some friends that we should cover the weep holes with wire mesh, to prevent bugs and other things from going inside. Is that a good idea? Please advise.

Comment: What type of weep holes are you referring to? Window weeps? Can you share a pic?

Comment: @shirlockhomes the weep holes on the brick wall

Answer (score 3):

Sorry thought this was for windows... Brick weep holes are different.  Wire mesh will keep out rodents and small animals.  Won't keep out bugs - your drywall does that.  I would try steel wool.

Comment: Be wary with steel wool... it could rust and make a rusty stain down the brickwork.

Answer (score 0):

Minimally compressed open cell foam.

Comment: Or how about a folded or rolled scuffing or scrubbing pad? Does not retain much moisture and you may find a color that's not too obvious.